# Is AlertIOS in React Native an outdated component?

Tags: react-native

I am learning React Native and what I am learning from only talks about Alert, even for iOS. In the API/Docs I see [AlertIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alertios.html) and I am curious if it does something special or is lighter weight for an iOS only app than the regular Alert?

(I found no post that had a definitive answer, but all the AlertIOS posts seem to date back to 2015-ish.)

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about deprecation even in the latest version so I wouldn't assume so.

Comment: Yeah, the lesson just used another component that is deprecated and is not in the docs. So I can only guess that there may be some special iOS logic that AlertIOS uses... Now I am curious what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlertIOS is special as it allows users to enter information into the alert using AlertIOS.prompt. According to the React Native documentation this is only a common pattern on iOS which is why they only made it available with an iOS specific API.

React Native still supports and recommends using Alert if you do not need iOS specific functionality.

[From the alert docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html)

> This is an API that works both on iOS and Android and can show static
>   alerts. To show an alert that prompts the user to enter some
>   information, see AlertIOS; entering text in an alert is common on iOS
>   only.

[From the alertIOS docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alertios.html)

> We recommend using the Alert.alert method for cross-platform support
>   if you don't need to create iOS-only prompts.

Comment: Is AlertIOS only for instances where you want an alert only on iOS and not Android? I am trying to picture when you would use AlertIOS over Alert.

Comment: Yup! Having a modal with a text input box is a supported pattern in iOS development but not in Android development. You would only use AlertIOS for iOS and if you wanted to support android, you would have to provide a different user experience or build something with the [modal component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html).

Comment: @gokujou did this answer your question? If so could you accept it, otherwise could you let us know so I or someone else could clarify?